# Packing tiled rasters into a Geopackage in QGIS 3.0.3 whilst maintaining the colour

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, geopackage

I have a folder containing 79 tiled Geotiff rasters making up a basemap of the UK. My goal is to efficiently store these in a Geopackage which already contains some vector data also used for base mapping.

- The tiled images are all single band paletted images, and are 8 bit unsigned integers.

Here is an example segment:
[image]

So far I have tried merging all tiles into a mosaic using the merge tool in QGIS 3.0.3. I enabled the "Grab psuedocolor table from first layer" option and then tried selecting an appropriate data type. They did not have 8 bit unsigned integer so the closest I got was 16 bit unsigned integer (I am not sure if this messes things up).

I then used the translate tool to save it into the geopackage but the results come out as below:
[image]

Is it possible to nicely stored these into a Geopackage or is it not possible yet?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those tiffs don't share a color palette so "Grab psuedocolor table from first layer"  is  probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that maybe `merge` without selecting the "Grab psuedocolor table from first layer" would work, but I just end up with a black and white image.

I then thought that creating a VRT would work, but that fails horribly with just primary colour squares for each tile, until you remember to uncheck `layer stack`. But when you save it as a GeoPackage it becomes black and white.

The only solution I can come up with is to use `PCT to RGB` on each tile before combining them (I would probably go with a VRT rather than merge) and then saving as a GeoPackage layer.

I used a zsh loop to do this:

```
for i in tq/TQ??.tif
do
  pct2rgb.py $i ${i:r}_new.tif -of GTiff -b 1
done
```

Comment: Thanks for testing this - your solution worked for me, and thanks for the code

Comment: Does a VRT need to be stored with the original images? So if I save the VRT into a Geopackage how does this work?

Comment: I think that QGis will use the VRT to look up each tile, but writes the actual pixels into the GeoPackage so it becomes independent.

Comment: I get this error when trying to build a VRT with the RGB tilesTraceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\Datasources2Vrt.py", line 102, in processAlgorithm
feedback=feedback)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\Datasources2Vrt.py", line 133, in mergeDataSources2Vrt
self.tr('Invalid datasource: {}'.format(inFile)))
_core.QgsProcessingException: Invalid datasource: C:/Users/AWGIS/Desktop/UK & Ireland Panorama 200 v2018/PCT to RGB/PCBHP.tif

Execution failed after 6.92 seconds

Comment: I usually try to avoid spaces in my paths as this can often cause issues